# WebStorm can't find node interpreter

Tags: node.js, webstorm, manjaro

I'm running Manjaro, I have node in *PATH*, it's located at `/usr/bin/node` and I can invoke it from the terminal using `node`, as expected. But when I try to add the interpreter to WebStorm, when I open the dialog for adding Node & npm executables and navigate to `/usr/bin`, it simply doesn't show up there. I've installed WebStorm through *flatpak*. Any ideas?

Comment: 1) https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/ioyfrl/jet_brains_ide_users/ -- "These don't work because **flatpaks sandbox them**. They can't use anything on the system (like `/usr/bin/node`)" 2) https://github.com/flathub/com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate/issues/24

Comment: Sadly cannot find a thread/link now where it is discussed in details on how it all works (as far as I remember it was a ticket on Flatpak GitHub about git/docker/node usage from inside the IDE/another tool and why only some work. As far as I remember (which I may be wrong right now) it was because it either has to be explicitly allowed/granted ... or it came bundled with the package).

Comment: Check comments in [this IDEA-189485 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189485) -- they will clarify some things for you , e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189485#focus=Comments-27-3191881.0-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to fix this by uninstalling the `flatpak` *WebStorm* instance that I had installed and installed *WebStorm* through [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/webstorm/manjaro) store. It simply worked afterwards, but I'll keep the question open in case anyone has a better solution.

Comment: I've had the same problem with Visual Studio Code (flatpak version) and it has been solved with snap version. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Flatpak is sandboxed, so it cannot directly run anything that is on the host, outside of the user's home directory.

However, there is a way to get around this, by having flatpak run the host binary using the `flatpak-spawn`.

---

#### Solution

**1. Run these two commands in shell:**

```sh
printf '#!/usr/bin/env sh\nflatpak-spawn --host node "$@"\n' > ~/flatpak-node
```

```sh
chmod a+x ~/flatpak-node
```

**2. In WebStorm, go to**

`File` > `Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `Node.js and NPM` (or `TypeScript`)

and set the `Node Interpreter` to `~/flatpak-node`.

---

#### Explanation

This will create an executable file called `flatpak-node` in your home directory, with this content:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
flatpak-spawn --host node "$@"
```

This will tell Flatpak to run the `node` binary on the host and pass along any parameters.  It works because the executable we created is in the home directory, and `flatpak-spawn` can run the command as if it was on the host (outside of the sandbox).

Personally, I make the file `~/bin/flatpak-node`, but you can put it anywhere in the home directory.

---

#### Bonus PHP

Of note is this same solution works for **PhpStorm** and the `php` interpreter.  Simply replace `node` with `php` in the content and filename:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
flatpak-spawn --host php "$@"
```

Comment: I was unable to use this solution on Manjaro linux with Visual Studio Code (plugin: SonarLint) but I really appreciate the effort and explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

##### If your WebStorm detects the node interpreter, but won't let you use it via terminal

For anyone stumbling onto this in the future, and your flatpak installation detects a node interpreter (using `Shift+F10` works), but using `node` or `npm` via WebStorm's terminal *doesn't* work, you may be able to fix that by switching the default terminal in WebStorm from `sh` to `bash`:

`File` > `Settings` > `Tools` > `Terminal`; then set `Shell Path` to `/bin/bash`

If this doesn't work for you (and nor does [Sarke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586183/4513452)), skip to the second part of my answer.

This worked for me, having installed WebStorm via the [Pop Shop](https://pop.system76.com/). Honestly, I'm not sure why that fixes it, nor why WebStorm doesn't automatically use the default shell.

---

##### If you've followed Sarke's answer and are still having trouble

If you've followed [Sarke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586183/4513452) (*there was **no default** node interpreter*, or you've skipped here from part 1 of my answer) and you're still having trouble, you *can* follow roughly the same instructions to allow WebStorm to access your entire host terminal:

```bash
printf '#!/usr/bin/env sh\nflatpak-spawn --host bash "$@"\n' > ~/flatpak-bash
```

```bash
chmod a+x ~/flatpak-bash
```

Then set *that* as your default terminal (using the same instructions from part 1, but with `flatpak-bash`), which will allow you to run your entire terminal outside of flatpak's sandbox.

However, by doing so, you'll run into [this error](https://superuser.com/q/410472/1022664), which means you'll lose the ability to terminate programs (i.e. use `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`) within WebStorm. In theory, part 3 should solve that problem, though I was unable to get it working myself due to incomplete documentation.

---

##### If you've followed the previous part of my answer and are unsatisfied

To avoid [this error](https://superuser.com/q/410472/1022664) (i.e. the ability to terminate programs, etc.), you *should* (in theory) be able to use [1player's host-spawn](https://github.com/1player/host-spawn), which reimpliments `flatpak-spawn` and should support termination of programs in WebStorm. To do so, you'll need to "install" `host-spawn` (i.e. [download a binary](https://github.com/1player/host-spawn/releases), give it execution permissions `chmod a+x ~/host-spawn`, move it to `~/bin`), then [create a symlink for your chosen shell](https://github.com/1player/host-spawn#creating-shims-for-host-binaries). Hopefully there is better documentation on its homepage by the time someone finds this, as I was not able to actually get this working myself.