# WebStorm doesn't show some directories on Linux so I can't run terminal with node

Tags: node.js, webstorm, linux-mint, flatpak

I am using Linux Mint and cannot run node in WebStorm. This is because WebStorm not sees the node directory. How can I solve this problem?

I gave read-write permission with the `chmod` command but it still didn't show up.

[image: this problem...]

Comment: Why are you developing outside of your home directory?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: @stdunbar When I type node -v in terminal, I get node: no command error.
Node no executable found in &PATH error appears in webstorm settings as well.

Comment: How did you install WebStorm? Is it flatpak, snap, JetBrains Toolbox app, or from ZIP file? That can play a role here, especially if it's flatpak.

Comment: @LazyOne I installed via linux mint's internal software manager. I think it's flatpak

Comment: Have you installed Node [as per the instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)?

Comment: yes I can run and use node from linux's own terminal. @stdunbar

Comment: The problem was that it was flatpak... when I installed it with zip, the problem was fixed. Thanks @LazyOne

Comment: @Burak You may still be able to use flatpak-installed WebStorm -- check the comments (and links) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73900621/how-to-open-var-www-html-in-phpstorm#comment130487968_73900621 as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957896/webstorm-cant-find-node-interpreter#comment114855926_64957896 . But overall (to not to have headaches) -- using a ZIP or JetBrains Toolbox installation is a better choice to avoid this kind of issues.